# Laravel show only record belong to user with relationships

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

I have builded a system in larvel and vue js, so i have some users who can have access on this system. Now i need for each user they to see only data belongs to his team where hi is on this team. I have some workers, teams, and jobs. When a worker is created, a user is also created in the users table. the user that is created takes a field called worker_id that corresponds to the id of the worker that is created. Now this worker is in a team, and several jobs have been assigned to this team. I want that when this user who has the same worker_id with worker->id logs in, he can only see the jobs assigned to his team.

jobcontroller function to show jobs

```
$jobs = Job::with(['teams', 'clients'])
    ->whereHas('teams', function ($q) {
        return $q->where('id', auth()->user()->worker_id); //i know there is wrong, iam just trying
    })
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate($paginate);

return JobResource::collection($jobs);
```

jobrelationships

```
public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
}


public function clients()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Client::class);
}
```

teamrelationship

```
    public function jobs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Job::class);
    }
```

workerrelationsip

```
    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Team::class);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example you are attempting to query for teams by using the worker ID, rather than querying for teams using the worker's team ID.

```php
$workerId = auth()->user()->id;

$jobs = Job::with('teams.workers')
    ->whereHas('teams.workers', function ($q) { return $q->where('id', $workerId); })
    ->orderBy('id', 'DESC')
    ->paginate(10);

return JobResource::collection($jobs);
```

Comment: I want to compare the worker who is part of this team, I don't want to get the team id

Comment: The snippet in my answer should attempt to retrieve jobs which are associated with the worker's team ID. You have described a database schema in which: User has one Worker, Worker has one team, and Team has many jobs. Therefore the snippet get's the User's Worker, and then the Worker's Team. The Team's ID is then used to query for Jobs. It would be useful if you could update your post with any errors, and the migrations you are using.

Comment: you are right about relations, but users and workers does not have relationships. Just when worker is created also create a user with same worker_id as worker->id. There `return $q->where('id', $team->id);` i need something like this `$q->where('worker_id', auth()->user()->id)